# CsvHelper discards row if there is a missing field

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have a CSV files that can be structured similar to the following:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3 
1,2,3 
5,,6 
4,4,4
```

When using Josh Close's CsvHelper and calling `GetRecords<T>` as per:

```
List<TestData> data = csvReader.GetRecords<TestData>();
```

The list of data does not contain the second row. I've tinkered with the settings and tried to implement a double converter that accepts an empty string and returns '0' when empty however the row still gets discarded. **I'm trying to avoid doing a manual get for each field.** However, I would still be happy with a row by row solution, i.e. `csvReader.GetRecord<TestData>()` nested in a loop.

I have the following test code:

```
public class When_importing_csv_with_missing_filed
{
    [Test]
    public void Dont_discard_the_row_with_missing_field()
    {
        using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader("Test.csv"))
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists("Test.csv"));
            var reader = new CsvReader(textReader);
            reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TestMap>();
            reader.Configuration.IgnoreReadingExceptions = true;
            reader.Configuration.SkipEmptyRecords = false;
            List<TestData> testData = reader.GetRecords<TestData>().ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class TestMap : CsvClassMap<TestData>
{
    public override void CreateMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Header1).Name("Header1").TypeConverter<DoubleConverter>();
        Map(m => m.Header2).Name("Header2").TypeConverter<NullValueTypeConverter>();
        Map(m => m.Header3).Name("Header3").TypeConverter<DoubleConverter>();
    }
}

public class NullValueTypeConverter : DoubleConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(TypeConverterOptions options, string text)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? 0 : base.ConvertFromString(options, text);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(string);
    }
}

public class TestData
{
    public double? Header1 { get; set; }
    public double? Header2 { get; set; }
    public double? Header3 { get; set; }
}
```

Over to you..

Comment: Well, for starters, probably best to use `double?` rather than `double?` for the fields if they can be empty.  No idea if that will help the class do the mapping or not.

Comment: Oh that is how it is normally; still doesn't work with `double?`. Test code is in state of flux. Updated question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I know you've said you don't want to it manually, but I've found converting using a plugin method / expression much more flexible than the built in converters or deriving a new TypeConverter. Is it really that much more code?

Comment: Have you tried setting a default for that field? 
        Map(m => m.Header2).Name("Header2").Default( 0 );

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work completely fine for me.

Code:

```
void Main()
{
    using( var stream = new MemoryStream() )
    using( var writer = new StreamWriter( stream ) )
    using( var reader = new StreamReader( stream ) )
    using( var csv = new CsvReader( reader ) )
    {
        writer.WriteLine( "Header1,Header2,Header3" );
        writer.WriteLine( "1,2,3" );
        writer.WriteLine( "5,,6" );
        writer.WriteLine( "4,4,4" );
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TestMap>();
        csv.Configuration.IgnoreReadingExceptions = true;
        csv.Configuration.SkipEmptyRecords = false;
        var records = csv.GetRecords<TestData>().ToList();
        records.Dump();
    }

}

public class TestData
{
    public double? Header1 { get; set; }
    public double? Header2 { get; set; }
    public double? Header3 { get; set; }
}

public class TestMap : CsvClassMap<TestData>
{
    public override void CreateMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Header1).Name("Header1");
        Map(m => m.Header2).Name("Header2");
        Map(m => m.Header3).Name("Header3");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3
1       2       3
5       null    6
4       4       4
```